# Is it possible to have different gorm versions in plugins within a grails 3 application?

Tags: grails, plugins, grails-orm

I have a grails 3 application that makes heavy use of plugins.  Some of these plugins provide domain classes.  My application will not start unless *every* plugin has the same gorm version.  This is an annoyance for locally developed plugins, but can be a significant problem for using third-party plugins.

There are more details in the stacktrace, but the relevant parts appear to be:

```
Caused by: org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: Failed to introspect class: class (my class name)
    at grails.core.ArtefactHandlerAdapter.isArtefact(ArtefactHandlerAdapter.java:129)
    at grails.core.DefaultGrailsApplication.addOverridableArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:772)
    at org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.registerProvidedArtefacts(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:310)
```

I am currently using Grails 3.2.8 with GORM 6.1.3.RELEASE, but this happens with other non-matching versions for gorm as well.

If there is a better way to accomplish the bigger-picture goal, my big-picture goal is to use the grails ehcache plugin (currently at 3.0.0.M1) which requires gorm 6.1.x as a minimum.  Per conversations on that plugin github site, there is no problem using gorm 6.1 with grails 3.2.x, though this is not the default.

Is there any way to run a grails 3 application, using plugins which provide domain objects, in which these plugins have different minor versions of gorm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this, the answer was basically "no".

The longer answer is "not as long as the groovy version is changing in non-backwards-compatible ways", and apparently that happens a lot.

There are some comments from Graeme here: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10693 but to summarize: you have to use the same version of gorm across plugins, and also make sure any third-party plugins you rely on are on the same version.  This is only required for plugins that provide domain objects, at least!